# Error during uploading image to amazon server

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

What I'm trying to do is upload a image to my AWS.

when I click the send button, 'uploadData' method activate.

1. My network is stable, but the uploading always fail.
2. My Amazon configuration has no problem(I can excess dynamo database without connection error.)
3. Internet permission is already included in my manifest.

I guess my parameter in createUserFileManager or uploadContent has problem or my authorization process..I'm not sure.

Please help me.

Here's my uploadData method.

```
  public void uploadData(String path) {
    final String filepath=path;
    AWSMobileClient.initializeMobileClientIfNecessary(this);
    AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient()
            .createUserFileManager(AMAZON_S3_USER_FILES_BUCKET, null ,AMAZON_S3_USER_FILES_BUCKET_REGION, new UserFileManager.BuilderResultHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(final UserFileManager userFileManager) {
                    File file = new File(filepath);
                    userFileManager.uploadContent(file,"/public/new folder/" + file.getName(), new ContentProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(final ContentItem contentItem) {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, filepath);
                            finish();
                            // Handle successful action here
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressUpdate(final String fileName, final boolean isWaiting,
                                                     final long bytesCurrent, final long bytesTotal) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(final String fileName, final Exception ex) {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "upload failed");
                            // Handle error case here
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

And here's my logcat.

```
10-07 18:22:23.804 32219-32219/com.example.idolschool D/AWSMobileClient: AWS Mobile Client is OK
10-07 18:22:23.844 32219-32219/com.example.idolschool D/TransferSerivce: Starting Transfer Service
10-07 18:22:23.854 32219-32219/com.example.idolschool D/TransferSerivce: Network connected: true
10-07 18:22:23.854 32219-14188/com.example.idolschool D/TransferSerivce: Loading transfers from database
10-07 18:22:23.854 32219-14188/com.example.idolschool D/TransferSerivce: 0 transfers are loaded from database
10-07 18:22:23.884 32219-14189/com.example.idolschool I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-07 18:22:23.884 32219-14189/com.example.idolschool I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-07 18:22:25.154 32219-14189/com.example.idolschool I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-07 18:22:25.154 32219-14189/com.example.idolschool I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-07 18:22:25.784 32219-14189/com.example.idolschool I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-07 18:22:25.784 32219-14189/com.example.idolschool I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-07 18:22:26.474 32219-14189/com.example.idolschool I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-07 18:22:26.474 32219-14189/com.example.idolschool I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-07 18:22:26.904 32219-14189/com.example.idolschool E/UploadTask: Failed to upload: 20 due to Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0x7f94269100: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
10-07 18:22:26.904 32219-32219/com.example.idolschool D/Application: upload failed
10-07 18:23:23.914 32219-14188/com.example.idolschool D/TransferSerivce: Stop self
```

Thanks for read my question!
Any code request for solving my problem will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adjusting my IAM configuration and parameter of createUserFileManager which has been null to "public/"